# Django crispy forms: Exception while resolving variable 'form_html' in template 'bootstrap3/whole_uni_form.html'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-crispy-forms

I'm making my first Django app and I decided to use Crispy forms. When I'm accessing my view, it throws a bunch of weird [errors](http://pastebin.com/xgpaKAig) (I PasteBinned them because the listing is really, **really** big). The strange thing is, the form actually renders correctly.

My form class:

```
def _article_form_widget():
    return forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'rows': 30}
        )

# [...] Some other forms

class NewArticleForm(forms.Form):

    """New article form"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id  = 'new_article_form'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    name = forms.CharField(label='Article name', max_length=1100)
    slug = forms.SlugField(label='Article slug', max_length=1100)
    body = forms.CharField(label='Article body', widget=_article_form_widget())
```

My view:

```
class NewArticleView(FormView):

    form_class = NewArticleForm
    template_name = 'wiki/new_article.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.article = Article(body=form.cleaned_data['body'])
            self.article.save()
            self.main_alias = Alias(
                name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                slug=form.cleaned_data['slug'],
                article=self.article
            )
            self.main_alias.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('article-detail',
                            kwargs={'slug': self.main_alias.slug})
```

The template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New article</h1>

    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% crispy form %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I tried updating Django and django-crispy-forms, but no avail. Please help me solve this mystery.

Comment: Just FYI: the repo is here: https://github.com/art-solopov/mdwiki. I've pretty much given up on crispy-forms right now, writing my own custom tag instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here. The crispy templates look for a `tag` context variable which may or may not exist, and render stuff accordingly.

The reason you are seeing all those errors is because you have configured `DEBUG` level logging. When this is done for [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/#django-template), the docs say:

> Missing context variables are logged as DEBUG messages.

The errors are nothing to worry about and it's working as it should.

Looking at your Github repo it seems like you might have moved on already!

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! Could these missing context variables cause my tests to fail? That was my primary cause for the investigations.

Comment: I did move on, but only to have a working app with passing tests. I have a strong suspicion that my custom tag won't process some widgets correctly (like radio buttons).

Comment: Don't think it would affect your tests, but it depends what failures you got? Generally speaking having debug logging on django.template will give you far too much noise unless you are trying to debug some specific issue, so maybe try turning that off.

Comment: Doh, stupid me. The test was failing because I forgot to update a field name after renaming.
Which became really obvious after I removed the templates log.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you. Based on what you said, I've adjusted my logging settings to filter out Django template errors. It is a whole lot cleaner. I have awarded the bounty to you.